# React-Select -- Get unselected value

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm using react-select in my current app and can't seem to find a way to get the unselected value. I'm new to react so maybe there is a "react" way to do this that is not obvious to me. Seems weird that I can't find any mention of this anywhere.

This is the best way I could come up with, it just seems obtuse:

```
class ProductMultiSelect extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            selectedValues: []
        }

        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
    }

    onChange (value) {

        // Update Redux Form
        this.props.input.onChange(value)

        const newValues = value.map( product => product.value)

        if (newValues.length == 0 || newValues.length < this.state.selectedValues.length) {
            const removedValue = this.state.selectedValues.filter(x => newValues.indexOf(x) < 0 );
            this.setState({selectedValues: newValues})
        } else {
            const newValue = newValues.filter(x => this.state.selectedValues.indexOf(x) < 0 );
            this.setState({selectedValues: newValues})
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Select
                {...this.props}
                value={this.props.input.value}
                multi
                onChange={(value) => this.onChange(value)}
                onBlur={() => this.props.input.onBlur(this.props.input.value)}
                options={this.props.options}
                className='form-group'
            />
        )
    }
}

export default ProductMultiSelect
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you'd like people to help, you need to provide specific code pertaining to your issue.

Comment: Hey Traveling tech guy, there really isn't any specific code to show here. I'm simply asking if there is a way to get the unselected value using the react-select library as I can't find any mention of it in the docs or anywhere in my searches, which seems weird to me. Their docs say to ask questions like that here and tag them under react-select ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: you can just get the selected value and filter out other options from selected value. i saw the document of react-select and could not find direct method to get unselected for it.

Comment: @VishnuShekhawat That's the conclusion I came to, I've updated my question with my implementation. Thoughts?

Comment: seems OK now ..

Comment: provided an answer that I think is in the right direction - but I'm confused as to what you're actually doing with these variables of `removedValue` and `newValue` that you're creating within your conditional...

Comment: @ChristopherMesser The removedValue and newValue are used elsewhere to update a dynamic form that I am building. I need to add/remove parts based on the products they are selecting/deselecting from the multi select.

Comment: I see - in that case, I don't think my answer is too helpful unless you add some more pieces to your state like `removedValues` and `newValues`, then maybe you can make it work. In either case, I don't think it's a huge improvement over your solution, but it's at least keeping all important data within the state, rather than having miscellaneous variables floating around.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you want to access your unselected values. I'm assuming the unselected values were part of your previous state? If that's the case, you can access them in a version of `this.setState` that accepts a function instead of an object. It would look something like this (pulled from their documentation). If the values that were unselected were part of your previous state, you can do whatever you'd like with them inside of here.

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
  counter: prevState.counter + props.increment
}));
```

Reference here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous